# my CSS moves a div to the left when using javascript .Toggle (included screen-shot)

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I am building a menu for my site to target mobile devices, and my default Android browser is acting very funny. I've stripped everything down to bare minimum, and as basic as i could to test everything out.

I am using jquery's .Toggle function to have my menu appear and disappear. It functions perfectly. Just as intended in all browsers. I went to test it on my mobile device and it worked / looked perfect in Firefox. Then I went to test it in the default Android browser. To my dismay there was a problem.

When you click the div that toggles the menu to make it appear the div moves to the left leaving a gap on the right side of the menu. What is funny is that I have a div inside of the menu container that retains its 100% width, and extends to the far right side of the screen. The css for the div inside of the menu div has practically the exact same css. So I am so confused as to why it is retaining it's 100% width but not my div that appears when toggled. Does anyone have any ideas? Below is a screen shot of the issue and my code.

[image: screen-shot]

html

```
    <div id="mobilemenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="mobilemenu-catdrop">
        Categories
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var flip = 0;
    $("#click").click(function () {
    $("#mobilemenu").toggle( flip++ % 2 == 0 );
    });
</script>
```

css

```
    /* header */
header {
    background: #2e97de;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    border-bottom: #287eb9 1px solid;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    display: block;
}

/* mobile menu */
#mobilemenu {
    border-top: #8dc8f2 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
    background: #2e97de;
    display: none;
}

#mobilemenu ul {

}

#mobilemenu li {
    display: block;
}

#mobilemenu li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #95d3ff;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#mobilemenu-catdrop {
    width: 100%;
    background: #1e6291;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know the direct answer to your question but all browsers have their own quirks. Might I suggest using [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) because that is the proper way in handling different screen sizes and different devices.

Comment: This isn't an issue of handling different screen sizes. This is an issues of CSS gone wrong. Even with a media query it would still be the exact CSS inside of that media query. So the problem would still exist. Do you see what I mean? (I do use media queries, I took them out so I would have less code to troubleshoot. Determining what screen size a person is using isn't my problem right now. The CSS that will be displayed when doing that is the problem.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess I misunderstood how media-queries worked XD

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the div `#mobilemenu-catdrop` is actually beyond the width of `#mobilemenu` since you're using padding with 100% width. use the border-box you're using on the header with that div instead:

```
#mobilemenu-catdrop {
    width: 100%;
    background: #1e6291;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: I want everything to be 100% width. I like that the catdrop goes all the way to the right. I want #mobilemenu to do the same. I do not want the gap. I like that catdrop is going to the right. My problem isn't that catdrop is going beyond #mobilemenu. My problem is that #mobilemenu isn't reaching the far right side of the screen just like catdrop. My problem is that is you toggle open the #mobilemenu div for the first time it moves left and there is a gap to the right. But if you close and repopen it the gap is gone. Refresh the page and open the menu for the first time and there is a gap.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why #mobilemenu is shrinking in width. And why it only shrinks the first time you toggle open the menu. Nothing should be shrinking in width. Mobile menu does not have box sizing so it should go just as far as catdrop.

Comment: Both are 100% width, just catdrop is actually beyond 100% because the css is saying 100% width now add padding. By adding in the border-box you're telling catdrop to be at 100% including padding. Did you try my suggestion to see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: Oh, all right. i misunderstood what you said at first. Yes, the fact that it didn't have a box sizing so that the padding was added to it was the problem. With box sizing in place it is all 100% including the padding, and is no longer pushing my container